# Edge browser overwriting text field content with a tab when auto-repeating

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have come across a problem when using the edge browser, no other browser tested exhibits this behaviour.

I have a form with lots of text fields on it and when tabbing through them it all works as expected, then when I hold down the tab key and it auto-repeats, most of the text field contents are replaced with a tab character, what makes it worse is that a page refresh does not refresh the page, even a control refresh does not.

Does anyone have a way around this, other than not using the edge browser of course :)

Test page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form >
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx"><br>
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx"><br>
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx"><br>
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx"><br>
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx"><br>
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx">
<input type="text" value="xxxx"><br>
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in my EdgeHTML 18.18362. The input value won't change when I hold down tab in Edge, you could check [my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP0Q3.gif). And from the result, you could see that the values of the inputs can be refreshed after clicking button `Reset`. There might be something wrong with your Edge browser. You could try to test in others' Edge browsers to see if the issue occurs and try to update your Edge browser to the latest version or repair it and try again.

Comment: Hi thanks for testing, I have tried on 3 different computer with the same result. The reset button works, but a page refresh does not. Microsoft Edge 44.18362.387.0 and Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362

Comment: Done a repair and a reset, no change, still putting tabs into text fields :(

Comment: Slowing down the keyboard repeat a little does seem to have fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slowing down the keyboard repeat in windows settings a little does seem to have fixed the problem.